# Unable to access tensor model from android_assets

Tags: android, tensorflow

I'm getting the following error when I try to start the `ClassifierActivity`

I have added the model files in the assets folder
[image]

Any help is much appreciated

[image]

My `TensorFlowImageClassifier`

```
  public class TensorFlowImageClassifier implements Classifier {
  private static final String TAG = "TensorFlowImageClassifier";

  // Only return this many results with at least this confidence.
  private static final int MAX_RESULTS = 2;
  private static final float THRESHOLD = 0.1f;

  // Config values.
  private String inputName;
  private String outputName;
  private int inputSize;
  private int imageMean;
  private float imageStd;

  // Pre-allocated buffers.
  private Vector<String> labels = new Vector<String>();
  private int[] intValues;
  private float[] floatValues;
  private float[] outputs;
  private String[] outputNames;

  private boolean logStats = false;

  private TensorFlowInferenceInterface inferenceInterface;

  private TensorFlowImageClassifier() {}

  public static Classifier create(AssetManager assetManager, String modelFilename, String labelFilename, int inputSize,
  int imageMean,
  float imageStd,
  String inputName,
  String outputName) {
    TensorFlowImageClassifier c = new TensorFlowImageClassifier();
    c.inputName = inputName;
    c.outputName = outputName;
    // Read the label names into memory.
    // TODO(andrewharp): make this handle non-assets.
    String actualFilename = labelFilename.split("file:///android_asset/")[1];
    Log.i(TAG, "Reading labels from: " + actualFilename);
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try {
      br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(assetManager.open(actualFilename)));
      String line;
      while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        c.labels.add(line);
      }
      br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Problem reading label file!" , e);
    }

    c.inferenceInterface = new TensorFlowInferenceInterface(assetManager, modelFilename);

    // The shape of the output is [N, NUM_CLASSES], where N is the batch size.
    final Operation operation = c.inferenceInterface.graphOperation(outputName);
    final int numClasses = (int) operation.output(0).shape().size(1);
    Log.i(TAG, "Read " + c.labels.size() + " labels, output layer size is " + numClasses);

    // Ideally, inputSize could have been retrieved from the shape of the input operation.  Alas,
    // the placeholder node for input in the graphdef typically used does not specify a shape, so it
    // must be passed in as a parameter.
    c.inputSize = inputSize;
    c.imageMean = imageMean;
    c.imageStd = imageStd;

    // Pre-allocate buffers.
    c.outputNames = new String[] {outputName};
    c.intValues = new int[inputSize * inputSize];
    c.floatValues = new float[inputSize * inputSize * 3];
    c.outputs = new float[numClasses];

    return c;
  }

  @Override public List<Recognition> recognizeImage(final Bitmap bitmap) {
    // Log this method so that it can be analyzed with systrace.
    Trace.beginSection("recognizeImage");

    Trace.beginSection("preprocessBitmap");
    // Preprocess the image data from 0-255 int to normalized float based
    // on the provided parameters.
    bitmap.getPixels(intValues, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for (int i = 0; i < intValues.length; ++i) {
      final int val = intValues[i];
      floatValues[i * 3 + 0] = (((val >> 16) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
      floatValues[i * 3 + 1] = (((val >> 8) & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
      floatValues[i * 3 + 2] = ((val & 0xFF) - imageMean) / imageStd;
    }
    Trace.endSection();

    // Copy the input data into TensorFlow.
    Trace.beginSection("feed");
    inferenceInterface.feed(inputName, floatValues, 1, inputSize, inputSize, 3);
    Trace.endSection();

    // Run the inference call.
    Trace.beginSection("run");
    inferenceInterface.run(outputNames, logStats);
    Trace.endSection();

    // Copy the output Tensor back into the output array.
    Trace.beginSection("fetch");
    inferenceInterface.fetch(outputName, outputs);
    Trace.endSection();

    // Find the best classifications.
    PriorityQueue<Recognition> pq =
        new PriorityQueue<Recognition>(
            3,
            new Comparator<Recognition>() {
              @Override
              public int compare(Recognition lhs, Recognition rhs) {
                // Intentionally reversed to put high confidence at the head of the queue.
                return Float.compare(rhs.getConfidence(), lhs.getConfidence());
              }
            });
    for (int i = 0; i < outputs.length; ++i) {
      if (outputs[i] > THRESHOLD) {
        pq.add(
            new Recognition(
                "" + i, labels.size() > i ? labels.get(i) : "unknown", outputs[i], null));
      }
    }
    final ArrayList<Recognition> recognitions = new ArrayList<Recognition>();
    int recognitionsSize = Math.min(pq.size(), MAX_RESULTS);
    for (int i = 0; i < recognitionsSize; ++i) {
      recognitions.add(pq.poll());
    }
    Trace.endSection(); // "recognizeImage"
    return recognitions;
  }

  @Override public void enableStatLogging(boolean debug) {
    this.logStats = logStats;
  }

  @Override public String getStatString() {
    return inferenceInterface.getStatString();
  }

  @Override public void close() {
    inferenceInterface.close();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is quite a silly and the mistake I had done was that I'd specified some other path in the below-mentioned variables `MODEL_FILE` and `LABEL_FILE` for some reason while referring to other repos online anyway I've written the right one below. Sorry for posting such a silly question

```
private static final String MODEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/graph.pb";
private static final String LABEL_FILE = "file:///android_asset/labels.txt";
```